# Possible to register a Laravel policy without a model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authorization

I'm working on a Laravel project that leverages policies for authorization, and this works well when I'm authorizing an entity that has a corresponding model. However, not every entity I want to authorize has a corresponding model.

Is there a way to register a policy without a model (or is that fundamentally incorrect?), or should I take a different approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can with Gates, not with Policies.

- **Policies** are classes that organize authorization logic around a
  particular model or resource.
- **Gates** are useful to manage authorizations for business logic that don't involve a particular model or resource.

Here is Laravel documentation about Gates:

- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#gates

Comment: Thank you, this looks like the solution I need (obviously not very familiar with Laravel). Do you know if Gates have to be defined in the boot method of the AuthServiceProvider, or could a class be defined somewhere?

Comment: @Josh The Laravel way is to write the Gates authorization logic in the boot() method of the AuthServiceProvider. If you have dozens of gates, I guess you could write the logic elsewhere but you would still have to register it in the boot() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of Policies as when using  [Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources) in routes; there must be a corresponding model. Otherwise just spell it out with the Gates

Answer (score 1):

assume we need to have custom policy without any attached models(CustomPolicy).

in AuthServiceProvider.php

```
protected $policies = [
    'custom_policy_name' => CustomPolicy::class
];
```

in controller

```
$this->authorize('methodNameInCustomPolicyClass', 'custom_policy_name')
```